# Subdivision doesn't allow me to subdivide another side

Tags: modeling

I am sorry for the title since I was not sure what to put in it.

My problem is that I have this shape that is just a scaled Cube and I wish to subdivide first the top face and then the side face.
[image: My shape before subdivision]

After I subdivide the top face though, the center of the side face (noted by the dot in its center) changes and goes up a bit which stops me from subdividing that face since when I try to do it, it just makes some kind of weird subdivision to one edge.
[image: My Shape after subdivision]

What can I do?

Comment: You must have made a bad move somewhere before the subdivide

Comment: Seems like for some reason the second face is an NGon. Try with a new object.

Comment: I took a cube, scaled it at 1/4 of its original size in the Z axis and double in the Y axis and used grab to move it a bit up. What could have caused the bad move?

Comment: I tried with a new object and the same thing happened. It seems that every time i subdivide any of the faces, the other faces adjacent to it become Ngons.

Comment: @konaka - Your workflow is flawed. Either select the whole cube in Edit Mode and press "W" to Subdivide or press CTRL + R to add Loop Cuts.

Comment: oh ok I thought you wanted to subdivide the whole cube. Actually when you subdivide the top face you create some vertices that are also part of the side faces. As the little black dot of each face depends on its vertices, it is moved towards the new vertices. For example, create a simple plane, in vertex mode subdivide one of its edge, then swith to face mode, you'll see that the dot as moved.

Comment: yes it is now a ngone as you also create vertices on the side faces when you subdivide the top face

Comment: Oh. I think I misunderstood your problem. The reason the adjacent edges become Ngons is that when a face is subdivided, its edges are subdivided as well. Since there a faces sharing that edge with it, they will become Ngons, as one of its edges is now many edges. The reason the face has a higher center of geometry (the little dot) is because now its top edge is many edges (and many vertices). For clarification, an Ngon is a face with over 4 edges/vertices.

Comment: *" first the top face and then the side face"* why not both at once? Subdividing works only with quads. By subdividing one quad you make Ngon on the place of the quads which are connected to the subdivided one. Ngons won't be cut with edges by subdivision (only vertices on the border of the face will appear).